# How do I monitor performance of Azure Storage operations in my code?

Tags: performance, azure, monitoring, azure-storage, performancecounter

I have a web role that uses Azure Storage while serving requests. Now I see that requests are served damn slow - like dozens times slower that usual. I've looked over the performance counters saved by the role - they look usual to me. I've checked connectivity from my network to the role - it looks okay.

I suspect the problem might be with Azure Storage operations invoked from inside my service being rather slow for some periods of time and that would slow serving requests down.

How do I continuously gather data that would help me estimate performance of these requests? Is there anything like a performance counter that I could enable or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [storage logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests.aspx) and you can see the response times.  This is enabled easily on the new portal under configuration for a storage account.  You can graph the response times and see if they correlate to your slowness.